# Macbook power adapter issue: PPP003

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power, magsafe

I'm using Macbook Pro 15" Retina Late 2013. OS is Yosemite Public beta. Once in month I usually do diagnostics (Apple's boot time diagnostics, the when you press "D" ). The last the when I did it, I got PPP003 error code which was something like that: "Battery may not be charged. Try to disconnect MagSafe 2 power adapter ..."

Thing is, it charges well my laptop but both adapter and it's ending are heating. Adapter heating really bad but ending a bit less.

My question is if I use it like that, can it damage my laptop? Is it important to change adapter immediately or not to change at all?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Apple's boot time diagnostics, the when you press "D"

Comment: @Buscar웃 it's original adapter of my MBP. i never changed original. 85W

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same model and had the same issue.

Originally, I took the generic troubleshooting steps (reset SMC, unplug let sit, etc.). Didn't work. I then used isopropyl alcohol to clean both the magsafe adapter pins and the magsafe input on the machine. Ran the test again (multiple times) and no error occurred. This was a temporary solution.

A few weeks later, it occurred again so I opened a case # with Apple and took it into the Apple Store Genius Bar. The machine passed Apple's in-house diagnostics. They swapped out the Magsafe charger with a new one and the issue is yet to re-occur (been ~3 weeks).

I asked them the same question about the battery and they did not give me an answer (they don't "speculate"). I assume, however, that if it's incorrectly charging the battery for many cycles, the battery would be affected.

In short, temporary fix = isopropyl alcohol to clean the pins on adapter itself and in MBP. Actual fix = defective charger/hub, both of which covered under Warranty. Go to Apple for definitive diagnosis and receive either new charger or get machine serviced.

Also: it's completely normal for the adapter to get very hot when connected to the machine and charging.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in apple diagnostics.

Your battery has to be fully charged (green magsafe led) when running the test to prevent that error. The error appears only in the ONLINE version 1.0.10r2.

The original OFFLINE version 1.0 that came with your MBP is working correctly.

Don't worry about the adapter it's normal that it heats up, nothing is wrong with it.

Comment: If you know there is a bug, could you provide references/source for that claim.

Comment: This wasn’t the case with me. I used online diagnostics with a fully charged battery. I received the same error. After swapping magsafe’s I haven’t had it once. Almost 2 months now. Faulty magsafe charger.